# nested array/object creating html?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

```
var bbcodes = 
[{
   contents: {
     newBB:["b","u","i","list"],
     newBB:["j","k","l","m"],
     newBB:["close","stop","back","time"],
   },
}];


for(var j=0;j<bbcodes;j++){
    var temp= '<span class="button_wrap">'; 
    for (var i=0;i<bbcodes.contents.newBB.length;i++){
        temp += '<span class="easy_edit_button easy_button_'
        +bbcodes[j].contents.newBB[j]+'">' 
        +bbcodes[j].contents.newBB[j]+'</span><br />';
     }
}
$('body').append(temp+'</span>');
```

http://jsbin.com/equfow/1/edit

I'm trying to create this HTML markup in the end

```
<span class="button_wrap">
    <span class="easy_edit_button easy_button_b">b</span>
    <span class="easy_edit_button easy_button_i">i</span>
    <span class="easy_edit_button easy_button_u">u</span>
    <span class="easy_edit_button easy_button_list">list</span>
</span>
<span class="button_wrap">
    <span class="easy_edit_button easy_button_j">j</span>
    <span class="easy_edit_button easy_button_k">k</span>
    <span class="easy_edit_button easy_button_l">l</span>
    <span class="easy_edit_button easy_button_m">m</span>
</span>
<span class="button_wrap">
    <span class="easy_edit_button easy_button_close">close</span>
    <span class="easy_edit_button easy_button_stop">stop</span>
    <span class="easy_edit_button easy_button_back">back</span>
    <span class="easy_edit_button easy_button_time">time</span>
</span>
```

just having a difficult time getting the array and object for loop to work I guess???

Comment: You cannot use `new` like that since it's a reserved word. Wrap it in quotes. Secondly, you cannot re-use object keys over and over either. Just two things I noticed immediately.

Comment: well then how do I keep getting the same data like new is reused to get it to set correctly. Sorry just a newbie here :D

Comment: @JonathanSampson: There's no reserved word restriction on property names, though some old browsers will choke on it.

Comment: @CrazyTrain Trying to use `new` as a property index will result in an unexpected `:` message. It's a reserved word.

Comment: @JonathanSampson: There's no reserved word restriction on property names. If you got an unexpected `:` error, then you probably tried to type object literal syntax directly into a console, which is invalid because a `{` can't start a new line unless it's a block statement.

Comment: I changed the `new` to `newBB` no worries Jonathan I trust its reserved

Comment: @CrazyTrain Good catch; you're right.

Comment: Is there some specific reason for your current structuring of the `bbcodes` variable or can it be changed? Are you intending to extend the data in some way in the future or is this pretty fixed data and you have no restrictions on how it is formatted so long as it produces the intended markup?

Comment: for the users using this. I wanted to do this `bbcodes = "b,u,i,list|more,less,differnt"` and create a new button_wrap per | line so it was as easy as possible for them to add the bbcodes they want.

Comment: @EasyBB the bigger issue is that you can't use the same property name 3 times in one object whether its a legal name or not :)  See my answer below.

Comment: Does code make noise if it's never executed? I created [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asifrc/YJuES/) for you, but it looks like a lot of correct answers are already listed below.. I thought I'd share it anyway since it exists, but didn't want to clutter up all the answers. Let me know if you have any questions about my example..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, as I think you are suggesting, there is no restriction as to how `bbcodes` is formatted so long as it produces the correct markup that you have posted. Then I would re-structure it as follows and produce the markup using plain old javascript as follows.

Javascript

```
var bbcodes = [
    ["b", "u", "i", "list"],
    ["j", "k", "l", "m"],
    ["close", "stop", "back", "time"]
];


bbcodes.forEach(function (group) {
    var wrap = document.createElement("span");

    wrap.className = "button_wrap";

    group.forEach(function (item) {
        var button = document.createElement("span");

        button.className = "easy_edit_button easy_button_" + item;
        button.textContent = item;

        wrap.appendChild(button);
    });

    document.body.appendChild(wrap);
});
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/APYTW/)

Why? If the data is fixed then you don't need all the extra objects and as you had it you were using the same "key" multiple times, when it would need to be unique.

This is using [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), which can easily be [shimmed](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) or you could change to `while` or `for` loops.

**Update**: If you don't like to shim, then here is the above but converted to `while` loops, this is cross-browser friendly without the need to shim. And uses [document.createTextNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createTextNode) instead of [Node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent).

Javascript

```
var bbcodes = [
        ["b", "u", "i", "list"],
        ["j", "k", "l", "m"],
        ["close", "stop", "back", "time"]
    ],
    bbcodesLength = bbcodes.length,
    bbcodesIndex = 0,
    groupLength,
    groupIndex,
    group,
    item,
    wrap,
    button,
    text;

while (bbcodesIndex < bbcodesLength) {
    group = bbcodes[bbcodesIndex];
    wrap = document.createElement("span");
    wrap.className = "button_wrap";
    groupLength = group.length;
    groupIndex = 0;
    while (groupIndex < groupLength) {
        item = group[groupIndex];
        text = document.createTextNode(item);
        button = document.createElement("span");
        button.className = "easy_edit_button easy_button_" + item;
        button.appendChild(text);
        wrap.appendChild(button);
        groupIndex += 1;
    }

    document.body.appendChild(wrap);
    bbcodesIndex += 1;
}
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/dYxPJ/)

Comment: I understand now they need to be fixed. I was just trying to make this as easy as possible to the users adding the bbcodes that they want. And I understand pure js is best, but problem with that it isn't cross browser friendly. I started learning Vanilla, and wrote this awesome code completely in JavaScript, and well turns out IE7, IE8, and FF didn't like it very much :) using querySelectorAll, byId, and some others as well

Comment: I wouldn't assume many people are still covering IE7 anymore. IE8 has querySelectorAll.

Answer (score 0):

```
var bbcodes = 
[{
   contents: {
     new:["b","u","i","list"],
     new:["j","k","l","m"],
     new:["close","stop","back","time"],
   },
}];
```

That object won't work well.  You can't use the same key 3 times.  This should be a simple 2D array.

```
$('body').append(temp+'</span>');
```

Since jQuery appears to be available there are easier ways to do this.

Lets try this

```
    var bbcodes = [
    ["b","u","i","list"],
    ["j","k","l","m"],
    ["close","stop","back","time"]
];
var i,j,innerspan,outerspan,currentVal,classStr;
for(j=0;j<bbcodes.length;j++){

    outerSpan = $("<span>").addClass("button_wrap");

    for (i=0;i<bbcodes[j].length;i++){

        currentVal = bbcodes[j][i];
        classStr = "easy_edit_button easy_button_"+currentVal;
        innerspan = $("<span>").addClass(classStr).html(currentVal);
        outerSpan.append(innerspan); //add the inner span to the container span
     }
     $("body").append(outerSpan) // add each container span to the body.
}
```

working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EqjBq/

There are even nicer ways to do this type of thing using an MV? Library like KnockoutJS or Angular.  If you are going to be consistently hiding/displaying DOM elements based on values of a JS object you may want to look into one of those.

Comment: yeah I had some typos. I updated and linked a working jsFiddle.

Comment: Or you could just create objects with getter/setter methods that trigger events.

Answer (score 0):

The array join method is your friend for problems like this. If not for the need to tweak each class, I wouldn't even need the interior loop. It's especially powerful and concise for creating tables and lists when you don't need to add unique attributes.

```
var bbcodes = 
[
    ["b","u","i","list"],
    ["j","k","l","m"],
    ["close","stop","back","time"]
],
l = bbcodes.length,
joinRight = '<span class="easy_edit_button easy_button_',
joinLeft = '</span>',
outerJoinRight = '<span class="button_wrap">';

while(l--){
    var thisRow = bbcodes[l],
    ll = thisRow.length;

    while(ll--){
        thisRow[ll] += '">' + thisRow[ll];
    }

    bbcodes[l] = joinRight + thisRow.join(joinLeft+joinRight) + joinLeft;
}
bbcodes = outerJoinRight + bbcodes.join(joinLeft + outerJoinRight) + joinLeft;

document.body.innerHTML = bbcodes;
```